# Dynamic width changing jquery, what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, resize, window, refresh

I just got done coding my first website's index, and everything seems to be OK, except that image slider I made in jQuery.

I also made a piece of code that makes the slider larger or smaller considering the window's width, and it's working. But the problem is, it only works after I refresh the browser. I want to make it work instantaneously, so that while the user is resizing the browser, the slider gets accordingly a greater or smaller width.

Here's the code I wrote :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#homeSlider').css({
    width: ($(window).width())*0.3167
  });
});
$(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not just using css `width: 31.67%`?

Then you should wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`, because that will make sure that your silder allready exists when you call `$(window).resize()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
      $('#homeSlider').css({
        width: ($(window).width())*0.3167
      });
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't width:31.67% take that percentage of the containing div's width ? or is it the viewport ? I don't know really.

Comment: It's the width of the container div. But usually css is used to make a website responsive. You can also add the width to the container or wherever needed to make the slider adapting to the viewport.

Comment: If you want to try it with css and need help, you should post your html.

Comment: Oh okay. Because my container is smaller than the viewport. Does that force me to use jQuery ?

Comment: No it doesn't force you to use jQuery.

Comment: Then how do i make the percentage mean the viewport and not the containing div ?

Comment: I can't help you without seeing your html.

Comment: Hello friend, job done. Thank you so much, just had to make the width change general through the elements of the slide : container and images.

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_resize(){
  $('#homeSlider').css('width',(($(window).width())*0.3167));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
     set_resize();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    set_resize();
});
```